# IOS - Help understanding Storyboards - Why rootViewController keeps getting reloaded?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, retain

Googled all over but no luck thus far. Before I started using Storyboards, I had a couple applications that used multiple viewcontrollers.  When going back to a certain viewController (by dismissing a child viewcontroller), I'd find my original (or root) viewcontroller intact. 
Now that I'm trying storyboards, it seems my rootViewController gets reloaded from time to time, loosing all data and restarting fresh from viewDidLoad. I think this happens between transitions from one view controller to another. For example, from the rootViewController, I present another view controller. As I dismiss those other view controller to return to the rootViewController, it looks reloaded and fresh new. It only happens sometimes, maybe when the OS issues memory warning.  I noticed all variables in my rootViewController are reset and viewDidLoad is executed again (confirmed with NSLog).

Is this normal?

From all tutorials I've seen, they say if using Storyboards to leave the delegate method "applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOPtions" pretty much intact (whereas in my older application I'd do some viewcontroller alloc here.
I've tried the following, unsuccessfully:

```
// in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of delegate.m
[self.window.rootViewController retain]
```

did not work. My main viewController still gets released/reloaded from time to time

```
// in my viewDidLoad of viewcontroller.m
[self retain];
```

Didn't work either

Do I have to declare and allocate the viewController in my delegate file, and then assign it to rootViewController? I tried something like that but crashed, maybe not doing it right.

Thanks?

Comment: What's your environment ? ARC or non ARC. Don't use retain.

Comment: THANKS for replying.  xcode 4.2,  LLVM 3.0,  NOT using ARC.  Base SDK is 5.0 (armv7).  I can save a copy and convert it to ARC.  But I'm still clueless about whether or not Apple intended for the initial view controller to get reloaded like that, or if I'm missing a line of code somewhere.  Thanks!!

Comment: I think [this article](http://www.hollance.com/2010/12/how-to-program-for-low-memory-conditions/) has part of the answer. Views WILL BE UNLOADED during low memory (at least IOS5 and under). So he suggests using a custom INIT and ViewDidUnload to manage the objects you want to keep vs afford to loose.  Seems close to a solution, except INIT isn't called when using storyboards. But getting closer.

Comment: Are you sure it is being unloaded? What I see is views are reset and that can be corrected by setting up the views in the storyboard to retain their state by an identifier and checking the box to save state. Look for the restoration ID and set shouldRestoreApplicationState and shouldSaveApplicationState to YES in the AppDelegate.